# SQL: number of sessions per program

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query where I would include the count of users per program (think online games)

A simple way to get this data would be with a

```
SELECT Program_id, Count(User_ID)
FROM Participation
GROUP BY *Program_id*
```

In the participation table, I have one row per participant with the program id indicated x times for x participants.
I also have a *Program* table with a 1-1 connection with each program features (dates, price...)

With Excel, I would probably use a COUNTIF function to get the output. I would hence like an output as shown below:

**Program        Begin Date      End Date         Count Users     Price**

Am I missing something obvious? Do I only need a GROUP BY? Select Distinct on Program codes from the participation table? It is odd but I can't create a CTE for each program's participation.

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8sgU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxC8a.png)

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: Please [edit] any improvements directly into your question.

Comment: How can I add an attachment to my post?

Comment: You don't add an attachment, you click the edit button and add as formatted text. - which the help text explains how to do.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for CROSS APPLY based approach.

```sql
declare @participant table (Program_id int, UserID int, Family_ID int)
declare @program table(program_id int, programName varchar(30), price int)

insert into @participant values
(1, 101, 20)
,(1 ,102 ,20) 
,(1 ,103 ,20) 
,(1 ,104 ,21) 
,(1 ,105 ,21);

insert into @program values(1,'TestGame', 60);
SELECT * FROM @program as p
CROSS APPLY
(
select count(*) from @participant where program_id = p.program_id) as t(cnt)
```

| program_id | programName | price | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TestGame | 60 | 5 |

Comment: What if I have more than 1000 entries. Can I use this query in Azure Data Studio?

Comment: if it answers your question, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: unfortunately the tables already exist and I don't intend to declare new variables. I tried to use your cross apply approach but I got a syntax error after the parenthesis